# Update dictionary in one file and try to retrieve it from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I kept dictionary in one common file and update it using two different python files. Is there anyway to print all the values updated through both files?

common.py

```
common_dict = {}
**do something**
```

one.py

```
from common import *

**do something**
common_dict['one key1'] = 'one value1'
common_dict['one key2'] = 'one value2'
```

two.py

```
from common import *

**do something**
common_dict['two key1'] = 'two value1'
```

I need to print all the elements in common_dict dictionary at one print.

like

```
{'one key1': 'one value1', 'one key2': 'one value2', 'two key1': 'two value1'}
```

i try to print it in two.py, but its print below only.

```
{'two key1': 'two value1'}
```

Comment: When you do `from common import *` you import a **copy** of `common_dict` to that file. When you run `common_dict['one key1'] = 'one value1'` you update that copy, but not the one that's actually in `common.py`. That's why it isn't there anymore when you load it in `two.py`

Answer (score 0):

Each time you import `common.py`, it's reassigning the value of `common_dict` to `{}`, and you are never overwriting the value of `common_dict` in `common.py`. For something like this, you would be much better off storing the data in a file - either a `txt` or `csv` file. This way, you can edit and **save** data.

Answer (score 0):

one.py

```
from common import *
import two

common_dict['one key1'] = 'one value1'
common_dict['one key2'] = 'one value2'

two.common_dict = common_dict
```

two.py

```
from one import *

common_dict['two key1'] = 'two value1'

print(common_dict)
```